# Superimposing images in PHP

Tags: php, image-manipulation

Is there a PHP function that would allow me to superimpose an image over another one? If not, how can I accomplish this (not asking for code, just a list of steps)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose there are functions provided by GD (generally enabled on PHP installations) that might do just that.

For instance, maybe one of [`imagecopy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) or [`imagecopymerge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) functions, I'd say.

See **Example #1 Merging two copies of the PHP.net logo with 75% transparency** on the manual page of the second one *(quoting)* :

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$dest = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

There are also these two examples that might prove useful :

- [Adding watermarks to images using alpha channels](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php)
- and [Using imagecopymerge() to create a translucent watermark](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [GD graphics library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). There is an [example of creating a watermark](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php), which is basically the same thing using the [`imagecopymerge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) function.

Comment: +1 - for showing an example, rendering my answer obsolete. :)